How to calculate the non-linear function
Consider the following function:
$$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{14} {{A_i}} {\alpha _i}^{n - 1} = {1 \over {4n - 3}}$$
$$\left| {{\alpha _j}} \right| <= 1$$
To determine the value of ${A_i}$ and ${\alpha _i}$, I arbitrarily choose 28 values of $n$. The trust region algorithm is used to iterate in MATLAB. But after trying many initial values that cannot converge, are there any other ideas?

Where did you get this problem? What is the context?
